# Will a Thinkpad X61 run Ubuntu?

Tags: system-requirements

So I want to start collecting old Thinkpads and I think the X61s is a good place to start.
With 4gb ram and it's Integrated Intel X3100 will it run smoothly on Ubuntu and play low end games like Undertale? (I know there's a system requirements sheet for Ubuntu and Undertale but I had absolutely no clue what they meant!)

Comment: Ubuntu should run on that, I don't know about the vice-versa scenario. ...might as well check this:http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar?rq=1

Comment: you can try the live version from CD/DVD or flash memory without installing system if it works good you may install it (note that live version running slower than installed one). I have a machine running Ubuntu has less features than yours and it working well .